# How does the learning rate $\alpha$ vary in stationary and non-stationary environments?

Tags: monte-carlo-methods, temporal-difference-methods, environment, learning-rate

In Sutton and Barto's book (Chapter 6: TD learning, 2nd edition), he mentions two ways of updating value function:

1. Monte Carlo method: $V(S_t) \leftarrow V(S_t) + \alpha[G_t - V(S_t)]$.
2. TD(0) method: $V(S_t) \leftarrow V(S_t) + \alpha[R_{t+1} + \gamma V(S_{t+1}) - V(S_t)]$.

I understand that $\alpha$ acts like a learning rate where it take some proportion of MC/TD error and update value function.

From my understanding, in stationary environments, transition probability distribution and reward distribution don't vary with time. Hence, one should supposedly use $\alpha-$decay to update value functions. On the other hand, since distributions change with time in non-stationary environments, $\alpha$ should be kept constant so as to keep updating the value function with recent TD/MC errors (in other words, history doesn't matter).

What's been bothering me is that in Example 6.2, 6.5, and 6.7, probability and reward distribution doesn't change. So why is *constant-$\alpha$* being used?

**Question**: How does $\alpha$ vary in stationary and non-stationary environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why is *constant-$\alpha$* being used?

This is because control scenarios are inherently non-stationary with respect to value functions. Decaying alpha comes with a risk that improvements to the policy will occur progressively more slowly, because the impact to changing the policy will be learned slowly.

> From my understanding, in stationary environments, transition probability distribution and reward distribution don't vary with time.

This is correct when considering immediate reward and transitions from any give $(s,a)$ pair. However you are forgetting that the policy function $\pi(a|s)$ *does* vary with time whilst the agent is discovering the optimal policy, and this affects trajetories and expected values that are being estimated.

> **Question**: How does $\alpha$ vary in stationary and non-stationary environments?

For non-stationary environments, you will want to maintain some minimum learning rate $\alpha$ and also some mininum exploration ($\epsilon$ if you are using $\epsilon$-greedy exploration).

In stationary environments, then a learning rate schedule is still valid and may be useful. You will see it discussed in passing when referencing proofs of convergence for the basic algorithms.

For example in the [second edition of Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf) it says this regarding convergence of Q learning:

> Under this assumption and a variant of the usual stochastic approximation conditions on
> the sequence of step-size parameters, Q has been shown to converge with probability 1 to
> $q_*$.

The "usual stochastic approximation conditions on the sequence of step-size parameters" part is a reference to decaying the learning rate.

However, due to the added complexity of handling exploration vs exploitation, the inherently non-stationary nature of value predictions in control scenarios, and the difficulty of getting function approximation to work, discussions of learning rate decay is a minor detail in texts like Sutton & Barto.

Comment: I don't follow how "this affects trajectories and expected values that are being estimated" relate to non-stationary environment. Regardless of what policy I follow, for a particular state-action pair,  won't $R(s, a, s')$ be sampled from the same distribution (albeit, varying rewards)?

Comment: @user529295 Yes, but the total return is dependent on the whole trajectory, which in turn depends on the policy, which is changing. Hence non-stationary *expected returns* (not individual expected rewards) even if the environment is itself stationary

Comment: Ah! Makes sense.